# Find the simple path with at least 5 edges in directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, vertex, directed-graph

I have a question.
Given a directed graph (G = V, E) and the source vertex s from V group.
we want to check whether there is a simple path (no circles) from s to any vertex in G with at least 5 edges.
Offer as efficient an algorithm as possible that solves the problem for a graph G that can contain circles.

please I need your help

Thanks :-)

Comment: I've solved the same problem with graph G which can not contain circles.

Comment: Bellman-ford algorithm with cycle detection.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you mentioned @L

Comment: @LuaiGhunim, Bellman-Form detects cycles with a negative length, not any cycle.

Comment: @DAle it can also detect **any** cycle.

Comment: @LuaiGhunim I don’t understand how Bellman-Ford could find `s -> a -> b -> c -> a` cycle. Could you explain, please?

Answer (score 0):

We need to find any 5-edge simple directed path starting at vertex `s`.  This path will look like:

```
s -> a -> b -> c -> d -> e   (all distinct)
```

Now let's go through the all possible values of `c` (any vertex besides `s`) and then for every `c` value we can go through all edges that do not contain `s` and `c` vertices and for the edge `(x, y)` do the following:

```
if edge (s, x) exists and edge (y, c) exists
    put (x, y) in AB edges list
if edge (c, x) exists 
    put (x, y) in DE edges list
```

This can be done in `O(|E|)`. Then we need to find a pair of edges `(E1, E2)` such that `E1` is in `AB`, `E2` is in `DE` and they don't share any vertex in common. The latter can be done in `O(|E|)`.

We can take a graph `G' = (V, DE)` and find the degrees of the vertices. Then for every edge `(a, b)` from `AB` we need to check that

```
degree(a) + degree(b) = |DE| + x
```

where `x = 1` if `(a, b)` is in `DE`, otherwise `x = 0`. If this equality does not hold it means that there is an edge in `DE` that contains neither `a` nor `b` and we can just iterate through entire `DE` to find the answer.

The overall complexity will be `O(|V||E|)` with `O(|E|)` additional memory.